# What is the time complexity of push_front(), push_back(), pop_front(), pop_back() in C++ STL implementation of <list>?

Tags: c++, stl

Please explain me the time complexity of these operations in the linked-list i.e. list implementation by C++ STL. Is this a doubly linked list or what?

Comment: from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list): std::list is a container that supports constant time insertion and removal of elements from anywhere in the container. Fast random access is not supported. It is usually implemented as double-linked list.

Comment: Did you even try searching for std::list on google? This comes out on top: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: Yes I did search for answer. So what's a big deal I could not found answer or I might have skipped correct page. Most of the questions asked here have answers somewhere on web, this does not mean that we can not ask questions here, Isn't it good to have all the answers at one place. I DON'T KNOW WHY SO MANY DOWN VOTES AS IF I HAVE JUST KILLED YOU WITH THIS QUESTION, ONE GUY DOWNVOTES AND OTHERS JUST FOLLOW HIM

Answer (score 4):

Constant. And yes its a doubly linked list. Since C++11 singly linked list also exists as `std::forward_list`.